# InstallShield SQL .bak

Tags: sql, installation, windows-installer

The problem is that recently on my company we need to make an installer, since anyone haven't worked with InstallShield Before we have a lot of questions about it.

So here are the questions:

1. Am I able to restore a database using InstallShield? I mean, giving to it the path of the .bak file and then run a script and recover the database on mssql?
2. Does Install Shield have configuration files, so I'm able to change the files that are going to be used, depending on the client and the software version we are installing? Nowadays we use our own setup, but we have to select the files manually, so when a client whants to install a software we have to go with them and do it, because is really complex. Now we need to change that by making an installer that can be configured here in our company by and IT member, then send the files and the installer to the client and he only press "Next, Next..."

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that treating the front-end software and database as two separate items is easier for you and your clients. While many vendors offer the ability to run scripts against SQL Server (and other databases) during the course of the installation, you'll find that there are all kinds of issues you need to contend with (do you need to first install SQL Server, does the user have permission to access the SQL Server, what if they are installing the software on a new pc but don't need the database created again, etc). None of these are showstoppers, but they do create headaches that you need to deal with.

By treating the database and front-end separately, you can build an installation package that installs your front-end software and related components on the target machine. This in and of itself can be tricky to deal with depending upon how complex your software is and the amount of references and prerequisites you need to manage.

When it comes time to manage the database aspect of the program, you may find that the majority of your clients are capable of restoring a .bak file to their SQL Server, and the ones that aren't can always be assisted (probably remotely) by your staff.

If you discover that this isn't the case, you can always create a separate "Server" installation package that manages the database aspect of the installation.

With regards to your question about InstallShield, you'll probably find better information from their website and \ or sales staff, but here's a [list of their current features](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield/features.htm).

There are other vendors in the space as well, so look at all of them including [InstallAware](http://www.installaware.com/) and my personal favorite [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). Pick the one in your budget that offers the features you need. They all should offer trials as well. Download and use them before you buy to find one that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes installshield can call a script that will restore a db, you just need 
to do so in silent mode. and yes there is a cfg file for install shield. 
the documentation will show this in detail

here is some documentation for version 12 
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installs hield12helplib/IHelpContents.htm

they are currently on version 2012, however if you are doing this 
crossplatform, don't use installshield, but use installanywhere. it is cross 
platform.